# Can I Downgrade ipad mini?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, ios, downgrade

Now that the jailbreak for iOS 9.2.1 has been released, can I downgrade my iPad Mini 1 to older versions? It is so slow with 9.2.1.

Comment: There is no jailbreak for 32-bit iOS 9.2.1 devices. Unfortunately, the iPad Mini 1 has a 32-bit A5 chip. However, if you somehow managed to jailbreak the iPad Mini 1, you can try using the beehind program.